# Фразеологизмы

Tags: фразеология

Какова история происхождения фразеологизмов: "каков гусь" , "сколько лет сколько зим"?

Answer (score 1):

Выражение **"каков гусь!"** употребляется, когда речь идет о ловкаче или мошеннике, пройдохе(прост.): *Хорош гусь!* или *каков гусь!* (выражение удивления по поводу чьей-нибудь проделки, плутовства). Выражение появилось, вероятно, из-за того, что дикий гусь - весьма хитрая и осторожная птица, почему охота за нею очень трудна.

Выражение **"сколько лет сколько зим"**  имеет такую историю. Раньше когда-то говорили просто: «Сколько лет не виделись!» И вот по ассоциации со словом *лето* к словам *сколько лет* начали прибавлять и *сколько зим*. Так получилось потому, что долгое время в русском языке *лето* обозначало не жаркое время года, а календарный год , то есть двенадцать месяцев, а слово *год, година* — вообще время, пору и даже судьбу. И выражение *сколько лет* понималось как «сколько времени, сколько годов». 
*Год* в современном значении известен с XIII века. *Лето* же в смысле 'год' упоминается еще в «Договоре великого князя Олега с греками», заключенном в 907 году. 
Древний смысл слова *лето* — 'год', 'время' дошел до наших дней в словах: *летопись, летосчисление,* в диалектном *летось* (то есть 'в прошлом году'), *многолетние* травы, *столетие*, в здравице «Многая *лета.*..». И теперь еще мы спрашиваем: «Сколько ему лет?»

Comment: Долго думал насчет гуся. Не могу предметно возразить, но нре совсем мне нравится это объяснение. Понимаете, во-первых, такое ощущение, что речь идёт о домашнем гусе, ибо охотничьи поверья о хитрости дикого родственника сомнительны, да и вряд ли бы такое рапространение получили. 
А домашняя птица воспринимается скорее как чванливая и вредная птица.
Недаром Ивана Ивановича Иван Никифорович гусаком обозвал.